# iTextSharp or XSL-FO to create a PDF dynamically with fillable forms?

Tags: c#, pdf, itext, xsl-fo

This is my first stackoverflow question.
After days of research, I am still lost on how this can be done, if its even possible.
I am trying to create a PDF document using either iTextSharp or XSL-FO (FO.NET is what I am using currently). Creating the documnet is no problem. I need this documnet to have fields that the user can still fill in. 
I am aware of the ability to create a PDF form using acrobat, then using iTextSharp to fill in those fields. This can then be saved and the user can open the document and edit it.
The problem with this is, anytime the PDF "template" needs to be changed, someone has to edit the PDF document, then change the backend logic to handle the new field.

I am looking for a 100% dynamic solution. 
Ideally I would use XSL and FO to create this document without the need for an exisiting PDF document. I have found no way to create a fillable form using FO.NET, or even iTextSharp, without already having an exisiting PDF "template".

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe both the [RenderX XEP](http://www.renderx.com/tools/xep.html) and [Antenna House](http://www.antennahouse.com/product.htm) FO processors support PDF Forms. They aren't free and additional output modules *may* be required for PDF Forms.

Comment: This is true, they are not free.
I did find a product tht works, but it is also not free. - http://bitmiracle.com/pdf-library/?bytescout

Comment: Bit Miracle offers free licenses for Docotic.Pdf. See http://bitmiracle.com/pdf-library/free-pdf-library.aspx

Comment: I've got confirmation that FO.NET does not support the creation of form fields. I am currently looking into iTextSharp now for this ability, and it seems possible, but there is not much out there.

Comment: btw, iTextSharp since version 5.0 is not free (as in beer). you have to buy commercial license or license your code under Affero GPL v3. http://itextpdf.com/terms-of-use/