# Generate PDF/ Microsoft Word Reports using ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, xslt, pdf, ms-word

I want to ask for the best way to generate a PDF and Microsoft Word Documents using ASP.NET.

I have used XSLT transformation, but the results was not good, and the major of XSLT processors are commercial and not free.

I need to create a simple document have a header, footer and some tables and images.

can anyone provide me with the best technology to do this job.

Thanks

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12044620/saving-word-docx-files-as-pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this question a little while ago.
I wrote some really neat stuff for PDF generation.

[iTextSharp or XSL-FO to create a PDF dynamically with fillable forms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5082933/itextsharp-or-xsl-fo-to-create-a-pdf-dynamically-with-fillable-forms)

PM me and I can send you some files.

Answer (score 0):

IText is a good free library for creating PDF documents.[http://itextpdf.com](http://itextpdf.com/). Works great with both WinForms and ASP.Net.